# when data is inserted succesfull do mail to admin

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO crm (email, emailyes, naam, voornaam, titel, telefoon, doel, categorie, regio, uitschrijven, updaten, minprijs, maxprijs) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '$_POST[emailyes]', '$_POST[naam]', '$_POST[voornaam]', '$_POST[titel]', '$_POST[telefoon]', '$_POST[doel]', '$_POST[categorie]', '$_POST[regio]', '$_POST[uitschrijven]', '$_POST[updaten]', '$_POST[minprijs]', '$_POST[maxprijs]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

When insert is successful, I would like to be able to send an email to the admin, any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: So? Please research this yourself and try it at least once before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

As described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: not working maybe i must use my gmail account?